# UINavigationController pushViewController stoppes working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem with the UINavigationController. It about a client or serverside logout.

The idea for serverside logout is this, every 15 seconds a function is called that checks if the App is still logged in. If that is not the case then jump to the LoginViewController.

The Logout can also happen from the App itself. It executs simular code.

There are three relevant Controllers, LoginViewController is where we want to end up, SignOutController is where the 'Sign out'-Button is located and MainViewController.

Here are the relevant code parts.

First, the UINavigationController gets allcated like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    splashScreenViewController_ = [[SplashScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashScreenViewController" bundle:nil];

    uiNav_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:splashScreenViewController_];
    uiNav_.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    uiNav_.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    [window_ setRootViewController:uiNav_];

    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];


    return YES;
}
```

When the 'Sign out'-Button is pressed or the App figures out that the Server has forced a logout, this code is executed (same code, diffrent functions):

```
LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:loginView animated:YES];
[loginView release];
```

If its a Serverside Logout it just reloads the MainViewController, every 15 seconds you see the animation of MainViewController sliding in. Its goes in a cycle from there, every 15 seconds it reloads.

If you click the 'Sign out'-Button it jumps to MainViewController instead of LoginViewController and starts the same cycle discribed above.

P.S. I have checked if any importend variable is nil, and I have checked that initalisation code is actually executed.

Edit: I think I did not mention that. My app works 99% of the time. Just one in a while this happen that the Sign-out button does not work and I start this cycle. Normally it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the 15 second cycle where a new LoginViewController slides in it just seems you are not stopping to check if the app is logged in after realizing it wasn't. You should have some sort of boolean to store that and cancel the timer or whatever you use.

I don't understand what you say happens when you press the logout button, but I don't think you are making a good user interface.

I suggest you start the application by adding to the navigation controller the loginViewController as root. Then you add without animation the one you want to start with (for example MainViewController). Whenever the application is logged out of the service you pop the view controllers until the first one, which sould be the login one.

You have the method `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` for that.

If you want to preserve the splash screen you can set it as the root view controller of the app, and chenge it to the uiNavigationController when you have finished loading.

Comment: The Timer stopes automaticlly when your not on MainViewController anymore. If the NavigationController would work, it would not be a Problem.
When you press the Sign-out Button it just jumps to LoginViewController. I dont understand how that is bad user interface. I just wanted to suggest that the Sign-out Button is on another ViewController and you end up on MainView anyway.
I  will test your idea.

Comment: What I meant when i said it was a bad user interface was that it is a little akward to have the login view pushed into stack, as it slides in. Usually logins are the first view from which you advance to the main application, and when you logout you return to them.

Answer (score 0):

The timer won't stop automatically just because you've pushed a view on top of another.  It will be there until the controller it started on is released, which will only happen after it has been removed from the stack.

Also, you don't need to push MainViewController onto the stack after every check, you'll end up with multiple instances of it, each on top of another.

Also, without really knowing much about the architecture of the app, it would seem like a good idea to make LoginViewController modal, they really can't do anything if they've not logged in right?  A modally presented viewcontroller wouldn't be affected by the navigation stack, and would also retain the users navigation stack much easier than having to manually push/pop controllers.

Comment: Look at my edit, please. It actually works most of the time, so the timer actually stops, I can see it on the server, it does not get any messages anymore. I dont push MainViewController everytime I check, only if it does not move to LoginViewController I get that cycle problem.

Comment: It looks like a race condition if that's the case, the timer ticks at the same time that you press the sign out button; so you push LoginViewController, and then MainViewController immediately afterwards?  Have you tried printing out the navigation stack whenever this occurs?

Comment: MMhh, how do I print the navigation stack?

Comment: Something like this would work:  `int index = 0;
 for( UIViewController *viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers ) {
  NSLog(@"ViewController: %d: %@", index++, NSStringFromClass([[viewController class] ] );
 }`